# Matplotlib boxplot + imageshow (subplots)

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, subplot

I'm doing some methods for data visualization, being one of which to show the data with the box plot for this data, as follows:

```
def generate_data_heat_map(data, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, plot_title, file_path, box_plot=False):
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(plot_title)
    if box_plot:
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
        plt.boxplot(data.data.flatten(), sym='r+')
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)

    fig = plt.imshow(data.data, extent=[0, data.cols, data.rows, 0])
    plt.xlabel(x_axis_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_axis_label)
    plt.colorbar(fig)
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

With this code, this is the image that I get:

[image]

First of all, I didn't get why my fliers are not represented as red +, but with the standard pattern. Besides this, as I want to plot the box plot and the data side by side, I divided my  plot area. But this space is equally divided, and the figure plot gets really bad. I would like that the box plot took some as 1/3 of the plot area, and the data 2/3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your plot. Also, how are you calling this. If you pass an empty Data object then you will have no data to plot but zeros.

Comment: Sorry, @GraemeStuart. The images are there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a simple mistake with your matplotlib code. You are plotting over your own image.

Where you have:

```
if box_plot:
    plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
    plt.boxplot(data.data)
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
```

you need to specify the two rows of your subplots in both calls to `plt.subplots`

This will work.

```
if box_plot:
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.boxplot(data.data)
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
```

If you want to size the plots independently then you can use gridspec. You might want to plot them above one another like this...

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


def generate_data_heat_map(data, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, plot_title, file_path, box_plot=False):
    plt.figure()
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1,height_ratios=[1,4])
    if box_plot:
        plt.subplot(gs[0])
        plt.boxplot(data.data.flatten(), 0, 'rs', 0)
        plt.subplot(gs[1])

    plt.title(plot_title)    
    fig = plt.imshow(data.data, extent=[0, data.cols, data.rows, 0])
    plt.xlabel(x_axis_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_axis_label)
    plt.colorbar(fig)
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()

class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, rows=200, cols=300):
        # The data grid
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        # The 2D data structure
        self.data = np.zeros((rows, cols), float)

    def randomise(self):
        self.data = np.random.rand(*self.data.shape)

data = Data()
data.randomise()
generate_data_heat_map(data, 'x', 'y', 'title', 'heat_map', box_plot=True)
```

[image: nice plot]

Comment: Yeah, I figure out just right now. But I couldn't divide my space as I wanted so far.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, @GraemeStuart, but you know how can I change the height of the box plot? The output image is so weird to put in a system, thinking about design...

Comment: I have adjusted the code to give the plots on two rows and used gridspec `height_ratios` to shrink the boxplot.

Comment: As I see in your example, the title doesn't appears anymore, @GraemeStuart?

Comment: move the call to plt.title to below the subplot calls.

Comment: For curiosity, why if I put the box plot in vertical mode the heat map label overrides it but in horizontal mode everything is fine?